# Insert data from multiple non-joinable tables

Tags: sql, insert, oracle9i

I have 3 tables in an Oracle 9i db.  A joins with B, and B joins with C.  A & C have nothing to join on.  I'm attempting to insert rows into B with values from both A & C.  I started with this:

```
INSERT INTO b
(value1, 
value2, 
value3, 
value4)
(SELECT 
a.value1,
a.value2,
c.value3, 
c.value4
FROM a, c 
WHERE a.column1 = x  
AND c.column2 = y)
```

But since there isn't a join between tables a & c, I'm getting far more rows inserted than what I'm expecting.  Is there a way to split up the two select statements to grab some values from the a table and other values from the c criteria?  If so, what is the syntax?

Comment: If there is only one row in a where col1 = x, and only one row in c where col2 = y, this input should only input one row.  If x and y have multiple rows, you'd be inserting x*y rows.  You can try Select Distinct, but if values 1-4 are different for any rows, there would still be multiples.

Comment: And why are you using that implied join syntax? Very very poor coding practice.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no relation between A and C, the join would basically be a Cartesian Join.

Any conditions that you add will be specific to your requirement. If you can post some data from your tables, it would be helpful in understanding your case.

Let's say you have 2 tables Students (with 10 rows)  and Classes (3 rows), and you now want to insert rows into a third table (student_class_enrol). Unless you have some specific conditions, the basic insert would be...

```
insert into student_class_enrol (student_id, class_id)
select s.student_id, c.class_id
  from students s, classes c;
```

which will insert 30 rows enrolling each student for all 3 classes.

To avoid this Cartesian "situation", You can add the conditions directly after the query as you did in your question...

```
insert into student_class_enrol (student_id, class_id)
    select s.student_id, c.class_id
      from students s, classes c
      where (s.student_id not in (1,2,3) and c.class_id <> 4) ;
```

or add the conditions separately and then do the join..

```
insert into student_class_enrol (student_id, class_id)
    select s.student_id, c.class_id
      from (select student_id from students where student_id not in (1,2,3)) s
           (select class_id from class where class_id <> 4) c;
```

Comment: Based on the "getting far more rows..." I think the question is how to avoid the Cartesian product.